# ready function triggers in every page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app, if the user is not logged in, I am redirecting to a page, which has one br tag with a class. Like this

```
<br class="logged">
```

In the Javascript on ready of that function, I am triggering a modal as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.logged').ready(function(){
    $('#open-login').click();
 });

});
```

This is working fine, except this modal is getting triggered on every page of the app. I mean that br tag is there in only page of the app, how it is  **ready** for every page is what I don't understand. If anyone can tell what went wrong with my approach, it would be of great help.

ps: It's rails application

Comment: Where are you including this script? If it should only run on one page, include it only on that page.

Comment: But in rails, you get a single file to browser with all the JS in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($('.logged').length > 0)
    $('#open-login').click();
 }

});
```

Into if condition you can declare an element of specific page and in only that page you can execute an action.

Comment: Can you explain what length >0 does. After putting this in the code, made the modal did not trigger in any page

Comment: @gates length get the number of elements currently matched. here an example: https://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: @MarcoSantino, I just noticed that your code is missing the opening `{` of the if statement's block. That's probably why it didn't work for @gates.

Comment: @ShaneCavaliere Exactly :) Thanks both of you

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `.ready()` method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document. Attaching it to a `$('.logged')` selector still makes its handler function get called when the document is ready - it doesn't care about the selector.

[MarcoSantino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37155935/1942085) will work for your needs, although you may find it cleaner to add the `logged-in` class to the body tag instead of inserting a new br tag, and then use the following in your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($(body).hasClass('logged-in')) {
    $('#open-login').click();
  }
})
```

Comment: yes, this solution work only if body have class "logged-in" @shane-cavaliere

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not working for me

Comment: Yes, this will only work if you add the `logged-in` class to the body tag. If you're unable to make this change to your HTML for some reason, @MarcoSantino's answer will work just fine. However, this is the approach I would suggest instead of adding a br tag that presumably does nothing except hold that class.

Comment: This answer should almost work, is there anyways I can find if the children of body tag has a class called `logged'

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what @MarcoSantino's answer does.